# Javascript LiveValidation disable() not working on Check boxes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkboxlist, livevalidation

' On my form based on the field dropdown value, I am showing and hiding the checkboxes field. live validation disable() method is not working when I hide the checkbox field. But, It is working for text fields.'

```
<form method="post" name="TestForm" action="https://google.com/" onsubmit="return handleFormSubmit(this)" id="form94">


<div class="row">
   <div class="grid-layout-col">
      <div class="layout-col col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         <div id="formElement4" class="elq-field-style form-element-layout row">
            <div style="text-align:left;" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><label class="elq-label " for="fe1393">Experience<span class="elq-required">*</span></label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                     <div class="field-control-wrapper">
                        <select class="elq-item-select" id="fe1393" name="country" style="width:100%;" data-value="">
                           <option value="">Please Select</option>
                           <option value="Professional">Professional</option>
                           <option value="Student">Student</option>
                        </select>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="grid-layout-col">
      <div class="layout-col col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         <div id="formElement6" class="elq-field-style form-element-layout row">
            <div style="text-align:left;" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><label class="elq-label " for="fe1728">Company Name</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                     <div class="field-control-wrapper"><input type="text" class="elq-item-input" name="singleLineText2" id="fe1728" value="" style="width:100%;"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="grid-layout-col">
      <div class="layout-col col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         <div id="formElement8" class="elq-field-style form-element-layout row">
            <div style="text-align:left;" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><label class="elq-label " for="fe1729">skills</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                     <div class="field-control-wrapper" id="fe1729">
                        <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-Used Java for school projects_hvba7ekg" value="Used Java for school projects" name="checkboxes"><label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label" for="checkbox-Used Java for school projects_hvba7ekg">Used Java for school projects</label><br></div>
                        <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-0-1 years of professional experience_uwv0lzq" value="0-1 years of professional experience" name="checkboxes"><label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label" for="checkbox-0-1 years of professional experience_uwv0lzq">0-1 years of professional experience</label><br></div>
                        <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1-3 years of professional experience_jp55zebf" value="1-3 years of professional experience" name="checkboxes"><label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label" for="checkbox-1-3 years of professional experience_jp55zebf">1-3 years of professional experience</label><br></div>
                        <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-4+ years of professional experience_uey2b9qdk" value="4+ years of professional experience" name="checkboxes"><label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label" for="checkbox-4+ years of professional experience_uey2b9qdk">4+ years of professional experience</label><br></div>
                        <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-No recent experience_txh6181p" value="No recent experience" name="checkboxes"><label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label" for="checkbox-No recent experience_txh6181p">No recent experience</label><br></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

 <div class="row">
<div class="grid-layout-col">
<div class="layout-col col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div id="formElement10" class="elq-field-style form-element-layout row"><div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><div style="text-align:center;"><input type="Submit" class="submit-button-style " value="Submit" id="fe1398">
</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
    <\form>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://img03.en25.com/i/livevalidation_standalone.compressed.js"></script>
<script > function handleFormSubmit(ele) {
    var submitButton = ele.querySelector('input[type=submit]');
    var spinner = document.createElement('span');
    spinner.setAttribute('class', 'loader');
    submitButton.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    submitButton.style.cursor = 'wait';
    submitButton.parentNode.appendChild(spinner);
    return true;
}

function resetSubmitButton(e) {
    var submitButtons = e.target.form.getElementsByClassName('submit-button');
    for (var i = 0; i < submitButtons.length; i++) {
        submitButtons[i].disabled = false;
    }
}

function addChangeHandler(elements) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].addEventListener('change', resetSubmitButton);
    }
}
var form = document.getElementById('form94');
addChangeHandler(form.getElementsByTagName('input'));
addChangeHandler(form.getElementsByTagName('select'));
addChangeHandler(form.getElementsByTagName('textarea'));
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('#form94 input[data-subscription]');
if (nodes) {
    for (var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
        var status = nodes[i].dataset ? nodes[i].dataset.subscription : nodes[i].getAttribute('data-subscription');
        if (status === 'true') {
            nodes[i].checked = true;
        }
    }
};
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('#form94 select[data-value]');
if (nodes) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        var node = nodes[i];
        var selectedValue = node.dataset ? node.dataset.value : node.getAttribute('data-value');
        if (selectedValue) {
            for (var j = 0; j < node.options.length; j++) {
                if (node.options[j].value === selectedValue) {
                    node.options[j].selected = 'selected';
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
this.getParentElement = function(list) {
        return list[list.length - 1].parentElement
    };
</script>
```

**Validations based on the field(Experience) dropdown Selection**

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    
     <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(document).ready(function () { 

    $("#formElement6").css('display','none')
    $("#formElement8").css('display','none')
     $("#fe1393").on("change", function () {
        if (this.value === 'Student') 
        {
             $("#formElement6").css('display','block')
             $("#formElement8").css('display','none')
            student();
            professional(true)
            
            }
          else if (this.value === 'Professional'){
               $("#formElement6").css('display','none')
               $("#formElement8").css('display','block')
               professional();
               student(true);
               }
        });
        });
  
<script> 
    function student(showValidate) {
    
        var dom6 = document.querySelector('#form94 #fe1728');
                var fe1728 = new LiveValidation(dom6, { validMessage: "", onlyOnBlur: true, wait: 300 });
                    if (!showValidate) {
                        fe1728.enable();
                        fe1728.add(Validate.Presence, {
                            failureMessage: "This field is required"
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        fe1728.disable();
                    }
}
   

function professional(showValidate){
        
         var dom8 = document.querySelectorAll('#form94 [name="checkboxes"]');
        
    var fe1729 = new LiveValidation(dom8, {validMessage: "", onlyOnBlur: true, wait: 300, insertAfterWhatNode :this.getParentElement(dom8), isGroup: true}, true);
    
         if(!showValidate){
    
          fe1729.add(Validate.Custom, {against: function(value) {return !value.match(/(telnet|ftp|https?):\/\/(?:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\.|[a-z0-9]\.)+[a-z]{2,63}/i);}, failureMessage: "Value must not contain any URL's"});
    
            fe1729.add(Validate.Custom, {against: function(value) {return !value.match(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig);}, failureMessage: "Value must not contain any HTML"});
            fe1729.add(Validate.Presence, { 
    
                failureMessage: "This field is required"
            });
         }
         else {
                    
                    fe1729.disable();
    
    
                }
            }
         
</script>
```

CSS

```
 <style>
    .LV_invalid_field,input.LV_invalid_field:active,input.LV_invalid_field:hover,textarea.LV_invalid_field:active,textarea.LV_invalid_field:hover
{outline:1px solid #c00}
.LV_validation_message{font-weight:700;margin:0 0 0 5px}
.LV_valid{display:none}
.LV_invalid{color:#c00;font-size:10px}.
    </style>
```

' Where dom6 is a text field and dom8 is the checkbox field. text field disable() is working fine, checkboxes disable is not working'

When I first select the student option from the dropdown and submit the form, it is working. ( which means checkbox field on the background is not validating)

when I first select the professional option from the dropdown and then without submitting the form, I select the student option from the dropdown and try to submit the form - The form is not submitting in this case, which means the checkbox field(dom8) is still validating in the background.

' Thanks in advance'

Comment: Your code is not complete...

Comment: @Li-JyuGao updated the code please check

Comment: Case1 - When I first select the student option from the dropdown and submit the form, it is working. ( which means checkbox field on the background is not validating)

Comment: Case2 -  when I first select the professional option from the dropdown and then without submitting the form, I select the student option from the dropdown and try to submit the form - The form is not submitting in this case, which means the checkbox field(dom8) is still validating in the background.